# avant window navigator still starts at startup after i uninstalled

Tags: 11.04, troubleshooting, 32-bit

I have recently installed Avant Windows navigator for openbox and when I go to  other gui interfaces like Ubuntu Classic or Ubuntu it also starts so I uninstalled everything I installed to make it work in openbox

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tint2 lxterminal xcompmgr nitrogen guake
sudo apt-get autoremove openbox obconf libobparser21 openbox-xdgmenu openbox-themes \
                        libobrender21 obmenu lxappearance-obconf lxappearance lxterminal
```

then went in to Ubuntu software center and uninstalled avant window navigator. Still the stubborn app keeps booting when i restart my system. Since I have done this the system is very unstable. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit if that helps. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm... Strange, maybe you'd installed it two times, one through USC and other through a downloaded .deb package, if so it's needed to find the other AWN you installed and uninstall it. But probably, you didn't do that, so what to do? Try typing in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude purge avant-window-navigator
sudo apt-get -f avant-window-navigator
sudo apt-get autoremove avant-window-navigator
```

All these commands should fix your problem, but if not the last thing you can try is to search for `awn` or `avant-window-navigator` under Nautilus and when find any file related to AWN you delete it.

Comment: Rodrigo Martins Thank you that worked but it made my kde gui not load but i can fix that. The main issue is now taken care of. Thank You!

Comment: ty i wasn't sure how to accept the answer why i commented  but i figured it out

Comment: Glad it worked, I'm not totally sure how to fix the KDE gui, but if you get any trouble just ask for help!

Comment: Now you've accepted my answer you need to award the bounty, to do this click on the `award bounty` icon near my answer. Thanks!

Comment: i think i did brohow to i check to see if it went throu

Answer (score 0):

Go into **Startup Applications** and remove it from the list.

Comment: its unchecked but still coming up when i reboot

Comment: I removed avant navigator from startup applications still its in the startup can seem to get rid of this stubborn app lol